# Filter Number range Function Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

**SOLVED**

From a previous post I did and with the help of some suggestions I have managed to write a function that technically should be doing what I required it to. However the results are not entirely correct.

I have tried to add markup to the JS to explain what is going on, but to explain I have div's like follows:

```
<div class="section-link">
    <div class="price"> £59.99</div>
</div>
<div class="section-link">
    <div class="price"> £259.99</div>
</div>
```

I am trying to have the function hide all these div's and only show the ones if the price is within the given price range.

The data I am passing into the function is: `£0.01 - £59.99` or `£60.00 - £159.99` or `£160.00 - £500.00`

from using alert's everything is working fine, however when it gets to the if statement for the filter it is not filtering how it should be.

Any help appreciated

The js:

```
function price(string){ // passing in the strings as £0.01 - £59.99 and £60.00 - £159.99 etc
    $('.section-link').hide(); // hide all section-link div's'
    var range = string.replace(/\u00A3/g, ''); // strip pound sign's from range
    var rangearray = range.split("-"); // split into 2 value arrays
    lowarray = rangearray[0].toString(); // get low value as string
    higharray = rangearray[1].toString(); // get high value as string
    lowvalue = lowarray.replace(/ /g,''); // strip spaces
    highvalue = higharray.replace(/ /g,''); // strip spaces

    alert(lowvalue); // testing low value string (is alerting right) - 0.01
    alert(highvalue); // testing high value string (is alerting right) - 59.99

    $(".price").filter(function(){ //do a filter for all div's with the class of price
        var divprice = $(this).text().replace(/\u00A3/g, ''); // strip pound sign from price value
        var maindivprice = divprice.replace(/ /g,''); // strip spaces from price value
        if (maindivprice >= lowvalue && maindivprice <= highvalue) {
            alert(maindivprice); // alerting to see what prices it is saying are between the range (these are showing all the prices and not only ones between the range)
            $(this).parent().show(); // show this parents div
        } // filter to see if this price is in the price range
    }); 
}
```

Is it possibly something to do with the decimal points?

Comment: I think you were missing a `.` before `parent()`, right ?

Comment: your quick, I was hoping I fixed it in time

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the contents have been removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using parseFloat on your number variable, if this was a string then it is trying to compare a string value to a float value

```
lowvalue = parseFloat(lowarray.replace(/ /g,'')); // strip spaces
highvalue = parseFloat(higharray.replace(/ /g,'')); // strip spaces
var maindivprice = parseFloat(divprice.replace(/ /g,'')); // strip spaces from price value
```